# List google drive templates using google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way through google drive api to get a list of the templates in google drive, the ones that show in the UI you can do New->from a template? We want to be able to get both the general templates and the domain templates. Are the templates just google docs/sheets etc that can be copied? We want to create new docs/sheets from templates through the api.

Regards,
LT

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported by Drive API. [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) will only list your specific files and not the default templates. If you manually copy the templates and save them as your files, it'll appear in files.list.